# What is wrong with my C code? C code warning

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i=2,number;
    printf("Enter another number greater than 5\':");
    scanf("%d",number);
    while (number>5);
 
    for (; i<=3; i++) 
    {
        printf("Hi\n");
        ++i;
    }
 
    printf("Enter another number greater than 5\' to continue the cycle:");
    scanf("%d",number);
 
    printf("finish");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please format your question. What warning do you get?

Comment: `while (number > 5);` is an infinite loop if number is more than 5, since you don't change `number` inside the loop.

Comment: I suspect you want that to be around everything up to the next `scanf`. But the `;` at the end of the `while` line makes it an empty loop.

Comment: Also, `scanf("%d", number);` should pass `&number` instead.

Comment: You need `&number` instead of `number` in `scanf`, the `while` loop will never finish, the `for` loop will never run as `i` will never become 3, the cycle will continue no matter what they input (unlike what the second to last `printf` says), and you are incrementing `i` in the loop and in the third part of the `for` loop (although the `for` loop never runs anyways).  **Your program will most likely work if you fix these logical errors.**  Read over this and try fixing them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, within the two scanf functions you need to add *&* to the number parameter. It is because *&number* gets the address of *number*, and the value entered by the user is stored in that address. Also, your code never leaves the loop. Try like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    
    int number;
    printf("Enter a number greater than 5: ");
    scanf("%d",&number);
    while (number>5){
        for (int i = 0; i<1; i++){
        printf("Hi\n"); 
        }
        printf("Enter another number to continue the cycle: ");
        scanf("%d", &number);
    }
 
    printf("finish");
    return 0;
}
```

Remember that for loop already increments the counter *i* by itself, so the *i++* statement inside loop is unnecessary if you wanted to print "Hi!" only once (even the for loop is useless if you only wanted to print it once, but I guess you did it because you are learning).

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems:

## 1 Incorrect usage of `scanf`

`scanf` takes format string and then addresses to variables, so it could write to memory, where the variables are located.
So correct usage is

```
scanf("%d",&number);
```

Best would be to check also return value of `scanf`. `scanf` returns count of successfully loaded arguments. So in you case

```
if (scanf("%d", &number) != 1) {
   // print error message, or something else
}
```

If there were more arguments, then the condition would be different

```
if (scanf("%d %f %c %d", &a, &b, &c, &d) != 4) {
   // ...
}
```

## 2 Infinite `while` loop

`while (number>5);` is infinite loop if `number` is greater then 5.
`number` is not changed within the loop, so the condition for `while` loop would be always truthy.

## 3 Possibly wrong incrementation of `i` variable in `for` loop

```
// int i = 2;
for (; i<=3; i++) 
{
    printf("Hi\n");
    ++i;
}
```

There is suspicious `++i;` in the for loops body. This does not change the for loops behaviour, but I assume you are a beginner, so I will explain it anyway.

It will work like this:

1. for loop starts with no initialization (`i` is initialized to `2` outside of the loop)
2. condition `i <= 3` gets evaluated to 1 (C does not have boolean [true,false], so there are used numbers instead [0 == false, anything else == true])
3. `printf("Hi\n");` gets evaluated -> "Hi\n" gets printed
4. `++i;` gets evaluated -> `i` gets incremented to 3
5. update of for loop gets called (which is `i++`) -> `i` gets incremented to 4
6. condition `i <= 3` gets evaluated as 0, because 4 (value of `i`) is greater then 3
7. for loop gets finished

My point here is that the `i` is incremented twice every loop.
So it's the same like

```
for(; i <= 3; i += 2) {
   scanf("%d", &number);
}
```